# Why is TensorFlow putting all data into system memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I keep getting OOM error for system memory (not GPU memory) but I'm not sure which function is causing tensorflow to load everything into RAM. I ran an image classifier on a different dataset half current size a month ago and copied the code with some small changes. So there are two changes that could cause OOM compared to the previous dataset. 1) The image sizes are much larger, but I resized them to 224x224 early on so I don't think it should have any effect at runtime. 2) The dataset is double the size but I am not using cache or shuffle this time around, so I'm not sure why it isn't just the batch size being loaded into memory.

```
def read_and_decode(filename, label):
    # Returns a tensor with byte values of the entire contents of the input filename.
    img = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    # Decoding raw JPEG tensor data into 3D (RGB) uint8 pixel value tensor
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    #Resize
    img = tf.image.resize_with_pad(
      img,
      224,
      224,
      method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR,
      antialias=False
    )
    img = preprocess_input(img)
    return img, label

ds_oh = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_paths, oh_input))
ds_oh = ds_oh.map(read_and_decode)
```

All data is now in ds_oh, size 224x224, with correct labels.

```
def ds_split(ds, ds_size, shuffle_size, train_split=0.8, val_split=0.2, shuffle=True):
    assert (train_split + val_split) == 1
    
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(shuffle_size, seed=99)
    
    train_size = int(train_split * ds_size)
    val_size = int(val_split * ds_size)
    
    train_ds = ds.take(train_size)    
    val_ds = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
    
    return train_ds, val_ds

train_ds, val_ds = ds_split(ds_oh, len(img_paths), len(img_paths), train_split=0.8, val_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

Split into train and validate datasets, shuffled.

```
#One hot
#train_ds = train_ds.cache()
#train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(img_paths), reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

#val_ds = val_ds.cache()
val_ds = val_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Batching and prefetching, removing caching and shuffling for OOM error.

```
# input layers
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

base_model = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))(inputs)

# creating our new model head to combine with the ResNet base model
head_model = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(base_model)
head_model = Flatten(name='flatten')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dropout(0.2)(head_model)
head_model = Dense(512, activation='relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dropout(0.2)(head_model)
head_model = Dense(29, activation='softmax')(head_model)

# final configuration
model = Model(inputs, head_model)

model.layers[2].trainable = False

optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Model built

```
INITIAL_EPOCHS = 35

history = model.fit(train_ds,
                    epochs=INITIAL_EPOCHS,
                    validation_data=val_ds)
```

```
Epoch 1/35
```

Fails before first epoch

Comment: Batch size is 32, 26k images between train and val, 12GB system RAM, 16 GB VRAM

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, the problem was in splitting my tf.data dataset (all images are in one combined folder location) into train and val. The function I found online (ds_split) caused a memory leak for some reason. Even using td.data.take(1) caused an OOM error. I tried a second, similar function I found online and received the same issues.

I decided to use train_test_split from scikitlearn on the list of image file paths and labels and built of two tf.data datasets right off the bat. Everything appears to be working fine now.